# Can NoSQL (e.g. MongoDB) replace Data Grid solutions e.g. Oracle Coherence

Tags: mongodb, caching, datagrid, oracle-coherence, nosql

I'm looking for an opinion on replacing existing Data Grid (i.e. Oracle Coherence) with some document store alternative e.g. NoSQL MongoDB. I was think about the most important  pros and cons and came up with:

**NoSQL**

*Pros:*

1. No additional database
2. No ORM mapping necessary
3. Although the best query efficiency can be achieved when looking up by ID, other queries can be satisfied by map/reduce queries

*Cons:*

1. Quite difficult to achieve data consistency when updating multiple collections or even multiple rows in a same collection
2. Slower response time ? (i suspect that Coherence reponse time might be better)
3. A read operation can return old data

**Data Grid**

*Pros*

1. With a Data Grid it seems easier to keep data consistent e.g. the data grid becomes is a SOR (System of Record)
2. As Data Grid becomes SOR, all data should always be available in the grid
3. Remote Executors

*Cons*

1. Additional database means additional overhead & system/application requirements
2. With a huge amount of data and sharding in place any kind of queries can take a lot of time

Comment: Slower response times on a NoSQL solution is not right. Key lookups are usually faster.

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase Server is a very good replacement for Oracle Coherence particularly for enterprise class applications. Orbitz is a great example where large number of nodes of Coherence were replaced by 70 nodes of Couchbase.

You can read more about the Coherence replacement here: http://gigaom.com/cloud/balancing-oracle-and-open-source-at-orbitz/

Slides from an Orbitz presentation about Couchbase are also available here: http://www.slideshare.net/Couchbase/t1-s6-oww-usescouchbase

Pros:

- High availability of nodes using replication and failover (avoid cold cache scenarios)
- Sub-milli second latencies (built-in object level cache based on memcached)
- High read / write throughput (very low granularity of locking) ( http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/switches/ps9441/ps9670/white_paper_c11-708169.pdf)
- Strong consistency at a document / item level
- TTL / Expiry per document / item

Cons:

- Difficult to achieve consistency across multi-document updates. Can be achieved using sentinels. ( http://www.amainhobbies.com/FromTheCEO/2012/09/09/invalidating-couchbase-cache-entries-with-sentinels/ )

Answer (score 0):

It can, but so can a pen and paper system.

The question is, will it be an acceptable replacement. That wholly depends on the situation. In some cases a NoSQL solution is faster, more scalable than a relational solution, but in some situations it is essential to have some kind of support for longer running transactions and relational constraints.

It depends.

Answer (score 0):

You already gave the pros and cons in detail...
as iwein said it depends...

What are the queries that existing relational system forced?

we know that partitioning in nosql db's are easier than realtional db's...
So if you switch to mongo you can extend your systems performance more cheaper and quicker way...

if people are happy on your oracle system now. don't touch it :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - NoSQL can replace it. But a lot depends on what you are trying to do.
If you just need a simple document store with easy key based lookups - NoSQL is a no-brainer.

If you need an enterprise class solution with paid for support and features such as custom aggregation, entry processors etc etc. Maybe Coherence is what you want.

I've seen people build custom NoSQL solutions on top of Coherence - which is a really expensive thing to do.